# How does the SSH option CheckHostIP=yes really help me?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, man-in-the-middle

There are many discussions about this option and most people argue that "it improves security", "it protects you from MiTM attacks/DNS spoofing", etc., but I fail to see how that is true. `ssh_config(5)` says that the option

> allows ssh to detect if a host key changed due to DNS spoofing

but it still seems vague or even misleading, because

1. The option doesn't detect if a "host key has changed" but only if a host's IP has changed, and
2. It doesn't elaborate on what it does when it detects such a thing (for example, does it stop the connection from happening?).

Because of the vagueness of the documentation, other people even seem to believe that `CheckHostIP=yes` will **not** let you connect to a host that has changed its IP (i.e. it has a different IP than the one that is already recorded in `known_hosts`) which is **totally untrue,** at least as far as I can understand through my own tests.

- When I connect with `CheckHostIP=yes` (the default) to a remote server whose host key is already stored in `known_hosts`, but has changed its IP, the connection proceeds normally but I get a warning:

  > Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address [......]

  Also a new line is appended into `known_hosts`, containing the server's host key (which has not changed) and the new IP address (which is different). If the host later changes its IP again, the next time I connect to it with `CheckHostIP=yes`, a new line will be appended in `known_hosts` and so on.
- If I connect with `CheckHostIP=no` to a server that has changed its IP address, the connection proceeds (which is what also happens with `CheckHostIP=yes`), but this time without a warning or appending a new line in `known_hosts`.

So the only difference between `yes` and `no` seems to be a simple one-line warning upon connecting, plus the recording of new addresses in `known_hosts` every time the host changes its IP (effectively keeping a history record of a server's different IPs through time).

If that's the case, I'm not even sure that `CheckHostIP=yes` is better than `CheckHostIP=no`, because if the client machine was compromised the attacker would be able to deduce from `known_hosts` that

1. The server with the host key X has a dynamic IP, and
2. It has changed its IP address Y times.

Obviously it's not much and I doubt the attacker could actually do something with that bit of information, but it is leakage of information that would not happen with `CheckHostIP=no`.

I have tried the above with two separate SSH servers that have dynamic IPs. (I use a free DDNS service to connect to them).

Can an SSH guru confirm to me that this is all the protection `CheckHostIP=yes` offers (a warning that doesn't even ask for user interaction), or correct me if I am terribly wrong about something? Should I just always keep `CheckHostIP=no` for connections to servers that I know will be changing their IPs through time?

Comment: I'm not sure what's different in your config file, but when I connect to a known host on a different ip address it asks me if I'm sure I want to connect and makes me type yes before continuing.

Comment: I've used 2 different clients to connect to the server(s). One client is a raspberry pi (OpenSSH_7.9p1) and the other is my Android cellphone through Termux app (OpenSSH_8.3p1). In both cases the config file is untouched...

Comment: Perhaps it's a setting on the server itself? Recently I've been migrating my home server to a vm host. Ips have been changing during setup and any time ips changed I got warned the next time I connected to the host through either Manjaro (my workstation), Proxmox  sshing into the VMs/containers, my migrated server running Ubuntu (14.04>20.04) a Debian LXC, a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 I was going to use as the server before migrating my existing install into a VM, and even using Connectbot /Termbot from my android phone. In every case I have to accept the warning to connect if the ip has changed.

Comment: That's strange because what you're saying is that CheckHostIP=yes actually triggers an interactive prompt if the known host's IP has changed. The problem is that I tried the above with 2 _different_ remote servers, same result. I just checked right now connecting to one server with an untouched sshd_config file (OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2) that has just changed its IP, same result (as outlined in my post). I don't get it. I will try to ssh into both servers via another client later but I doubt I'll get different results...

Comment: I've experienced similar issues as the OP @AndroidX ,
 my initial guess was something related to having `AddKeysToAgent yes` for the `Host *` in the file `~/.ssh/config`. But after tinkering with it for a bit didn't seem to take effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Summary

In my view, [`CheckHostIP`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#CheckHostIP) just reassures you that an attacker who has **already compromised the remote server's private key** hasn't ***also* poisoned your local DNS.**

#### Side Note: Leak instructions

If you found this post because of a remote server's host key leaking,<sup>1</sup> follow the instructions from the service provider to cycle the relevant *known_hosts* entries. You may also want to remove the matching lines from *known_hosts* that `CheckHostIP` has added.

| Disclosure Date | Provider | Instructions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-24 | GitHub | [Blog post](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) |
| 2023-05-15 | Bitbucket | [Blog post](https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes) |

### Expert opinion

An "SSH guru," specifically an OpenSSH maintainer, [has affirmed your position](https://twitter.com/damienmiller/status/1337209188888375298).

> I think we're more likely to turn off `CheckHostIP` (the thing that spams addresses into *known_hosts*) in the short term, as nobody has satisfactorily explained what problem it solves to me.
>
> [@DamienMiller](https://twitter.com/damienmiller/status/1337209188888375298) (Twitter, 2020-12-11)

Three months later, Damien followed through in the release of [OpenSSH v8.5](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5) on 2021-03-03, where `CheckHostIP` was turned off with this changelog message:

> - [`ssh`(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1): disable `CheckHostIP` by default. It provides insignificant benefits while making key rotation significantly more difficult, especially for hosts behind IP-based load-balancers.

### Bringing back `CheckHostIP`

If you really want to keep `CheckHostIP`, you can turn it back on and disable it only for hosts with dynamic IPs to skip the warning and *known_hosts* pollution. Don't do this, though. It's not that helpful.

It seems pretty unlikely that `CheckHostIP` is a meaningful measure for dealing with a threat actor who can both…

- Steal the private key of the remote SSH server, *and*
- Manipulate your client's DNS resolution.

In the face of such a foe, it seems ludicrous that somehow you'll be saved by the "Warning: Permanently added host key" message when connecting to a host, especially when it shows you the warning<sup>2</sup> every single time.

#### The *known_hosts* trick

Some people [proactively dump](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94554/143088) all the known IPs for a service into a *known_hosts* line, probably just to avoid the warning message. That front-loads all the nonsense into *known_hosts* that you'd gradually accumulate otherwise, but I think it's missing the point: **The important part of *known_hosts* is not the IP—it's the host key.**

In order to cut down on the super-long *known_hosts* entries, other people [simulate IP ranges with wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164434/143088), which may *appear* clever, but it's actually finicky<sup>3</sup> and only works because `CheckHostIP` checks IPs and ignores hostnames.

<sub><sup>1</sup> For some reason, this post ranks fairly high in search results for *real* host key leaks.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> That is to say: "when it cries 'Wolf!'"</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> For example, if you try to allow `127.0.0.*` for your dynamic-IP SSH server, you technically also match `127.0.0.evilsite.example` because IPs and hostnames are not distinguished. You can limit wildcards to single characters with `?`, but be careful: `127.0.0.??` will match `127.0.0.cz`. Maybe it [seems unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-letter_second-level_domain) that `.cz` would allow `0` as a second-level domain, but we're talking about an adversary *who is poisoning your DNS!*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for citing a credible source. The spamming in known_hosts was getting really annoying