# How to remove all lines with the same public key from known_hosts?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sed, ssh-keygen

Let's imagine the following scenario.

I have an host key `ABCDEF1234` for a given hostname, so my `known_hosts` file looks like this (unhashed version):

```
example.com ssh-rsa ABCDEF1234
```

Now I connect to it, and hostnames resolve to 10.11.12.13
I have a message like this

`Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '10.11.12.13' to the list of known hosts.`

And my known_hosts looks like this

```
example.com ssh-rsa ABCDEF1234
192.0.2.1 ssh-rsa ABCDEF1234
```

Now a few month later, `example.com` admin tells me the RSA key is removed and changed in favour of `1234ABCDEF` key.
So I remove the offending key using `ssh-keygen -R example.com`, then I connect for the first time, accepts the key, and know my `known_host` looks like this:

```
192.0.2.1 ssh-rsa ABCDEF1234 
example.com  ssh-rsa 1234ABCDEF
```

And every time I connect I have this nice warning  message:

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'example.com' differs from the key for the IP address '192.0.2.1'
Offending key for IP in /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:162
Matching host key in /home/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:182
```

Now imagine there are tens or hundreds of IP for that particular hostname, that is quite a lot of lines to clean.
One solution is to use `sed` to remove matching lines, but isn't the goal of `ssh-keygen -R` to avoid messing with `sed`?

`sed -i '/ABCDEF1234/d' known_hosts`

Is there another solution, that would remove all entries from a `known_host` file that are associated with a given key, instead of an hostname or IP address ?

Comment: I think this post has your answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/123072/ssh-automatically-accept-keys

Comment: Why do you use: `ssh-keygen -R myhost.com` to remove the entry for myhost.com,, and do you not use: `ssh-keygen -R 10.11.12.13` to remove the entry for 10.11.12.13 ?

Comment: @Luuk Let's say github.com changes its rsa key, do you know all IP of github.com ?
Of course if I have  single ip, I can do waht you suggest.

Comment: That's why, when you connect to github.com, you will not use an ip-address, but use a hostname.

Comment: @Luuk Well on my ubuntu machine, if I connect by hostname, an entry is also added for the IP that hostname was resolved to. And the issue happen when there is a mismatch. But everything is already written above in the ticket, which deserves being read in full :)

Comment: shodanex: which Ubuntu? Adding both hostname and IP to `known_hosts` was long the default behavior in OpenSSH, but you could disable it by setting option `CheckHostIP = no` on the commandline with `-o` or in your config file(s). [OpenSSH 8.5 changed the default to no](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.5), and Ubuntu 22.04 up should have OpenSSH 8.9 up.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of `ssh-keygen -R` is not to avoid using `sed`, but to remove hashed hosts that, e.g., `sed` could not find. From [ssh-keygen(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen):

> `-R hostname`
>
> Removes all keys belonging to `hostname` from a `known_hosts` file. This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the `-H` option above).
>
> `-H`
>
> Hash a `known_hosts` file. This replaces all hostnames and addresses with hashed representations within the specified file; the original content is moved to a file with a `.old` suffix. These hashes may be used normally by `ssh` and `sshd`, but they do not reveal identifying information should the file's contents be disclosed. This option will not modify existing hashed hostnames and is therefore safe to use on files that mix hashed and non-hashed names.

## Considerations

#### Avoid collisions

Notice that it is best to use the full public key encoded in Base64 to avoid removing other keys. E.g., if you use just parts of the *header* your would end up removing all the keys of the same type:

| Base64 | ASCII | Ref. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTY` `AAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBB` | `....ecdsa-sha2-nistp256` `....nistp256...A` | [RFC 5656, 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1) |
| `AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIFKy` | `....ssh-ed25519... R²` | [RFC 8709, 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8709#section-4) |
| `AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ` | `...ssh-rsa...........` | [RFC 4253, 6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6) |

#### Adjust your `sed` for Base64

The Base64 encoded public key contains characters `A-Za-z0-9+/=`. As it can contain the `/` used in your `sed` example, you would like to use another character like `:`.

## Working examples

In the examples:

- The `AAAA+OLD/KEY=` is a placeholder for the **full** old public key.
- The `AAAA+NEW/KEY=` is a placeholder for the **full** new public key.

#### Remove all hosts having the same key

Use the full old key to remove all lines containing it:

`sed -i ':AAAA+OLD/KEY=:d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

#### Replace the old key with a new one

Use the full keys (old & new) to replace it on all lines containing the old key:

`sed -i 's:AAAA+OLD/KEY=:AAAA+NEW/KEY=:g' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

If the key type also changes, you would have to include it, e.g.,

`sed -i 's:ssh-rsa AAAA+OLD/KEY=:ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAA+NEW/KEY=:g' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

#### Remove keys for the hostname or IP

This is the only use case where you would use `ssh-keygen`.

`ssh-keygen -R example.com`

`ssh-keygen -R 192.0.2.1`

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding the issue in the first place is a good solution.
If known_hosts wasn't filled with entry for each and every IP for a given hostname, there would be no need to mess with sed. `ssh_keygen -R hostname` would be sufficient to perform key rotation.

So my solution to this is to set `CheckHostIP` to `no` in the ssh config.

[How does the SSH option CheckHostIP=yes really help me?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1040512/how-does-the-ssh-option-checkhostip-yes-really-help-me)